# Is there an equivalent of ownvalue?

Tags: performance-tuning, core-language

When

```
a = 1;
```

is executed, an ownvalue will be stored in symbol `a`, and the *rule corresponding to* ownvalue defined for `a` can be given by

```
OwnValues@a
(* {HoldPattern[a] :> 1} *)
```

My question is, is ownvalue unique in *Mathematica*? Can we achieve the same result and (at least almost) the same performance as ownvalue, with other functions?

`Replace` / `ReplaceAll` / `With` can give us the same result, but they're much slower:

```
a = 1;
Do[a, {10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming
Clear@a
(* {0.031268, Null} *)

Do[a /. {HoldPattern[a] :> 1}, {10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.456692, Null} *)

Do[Replace[a, {HoldPattern[a] :> 1}], {10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.518485, Null} *)


Do[With[{a = 1}, a], {10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.401429, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) is as close to what you seem to want as I am aware of:

```
asc = <|"a" -> 1|>;

Do[asc["a"], {10^6}] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.2063, Null} *)
```

Eliminating the look-up of `asc` itself makes this somewhat faster:

```
With[{asc = <|"a" -> 1|>},
  Do[asc["a"], {1*^6}] // RepeatedTiming
]

(* {0.142, Null} *)
```

Incidentally I think the "ownvalues" evaluation may not be as fast as it appears.  I mean that I think there may be optimization taking place that hides the actual look-up cost.

---

I am unable to support my conjecture above regarding optimizations.  Building a complete expression and then evaluating it is still much faster for Symbol lookup:

```
a = 1;
foo = Join @@ ConstantArray[Hold[a], 1*^6];
List @@ foo // RepeatedTiming // First

(* 0.0380 *)
```